# Get children under a parent using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, getelementbyid

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
 $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: 'some/url',
        data: {
              'name':'myname'   
              },
         success: function (result) {
      
          var result = ["student", "test"];
          var length = result.length;

          for (var i = 0; i < length; i++) {

            var datastores = result;

            $('#data_stores').append(
            "<div class='col-sm-8 col-md-8 col-lg-8 col-xs-8 pre-panel datastore' id=" +             datastores[i] + "> </div>");

          }
      }
 })
  var ids = $('#data_stores').children().map(function(){ return this.id }).get();


  $('<pre>').appendTo('body').text(JSON.stringify(ids));

})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="data_stores">
</div>
```

```
<div id="data_stores">

 <div class="col-sm-8 col-md-8 col-lg-8 col-xs-8 pre-panel datastore" id="students">

   //Some other codes here

 </div>

 <div class="col-sm-8 col-md-8 col-lg-8 col-xs-8 pre-panel datastore" id="teachers">

   //Some other codes here

 </div>

</div>
```

This is a block of code in my HTML. The inner divs under data_stores are created using jquery. The IDs of the children div were result of an AJAX request and assigned on success.

The problem is, I need the ID values of the children divs to use for another AJAX call.

I ran the following:

```
console.log($("#data_stores"));
```

Output I got is the same above.

But for,

```
console.log($("#data_stores").find('.datastore'));
```

> [prevObject: m.fn.init[1], context: document, selector: "#data_stores
>   .datstore"]

But, when accessing the child it says the element is undefined.

I need to do both AJAX calls on

```
$(document).ready(function() {
})
```

Comment: _"But, when accessing the child it says the element is undefined."_ Perhaps show that code, so we can help fix it.  Are you maybe trying to access them before the ajax call that adds them has happened?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/b6cyr0j9/

Comment: `.datastore` or `.datstore` ? Is your problem just a typo ?

Comment: @DenysSéguret np, the typo was only here

Comment: @Fasna Looking at my answer, can you spot what's different ?

Comment: @Fasna You should probably try to build a reproducible example of your problem (using the code snippet feature that you find in the toolbar when editing your question). If necessary we can close this question.

Comment: I added my code into code snippet

Answer (score 1):

Using `children` like this works:

```
var ids = $('#data_stores').children().map(function(){ return this.id }).get();
```

```js
var ids = $('#data_stores').children().map(function(){ return this.id }).get();

$('<pre>').appendTo('body').text(JSON.stringify(ids));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="data_stores">

 <div class="col-sm-8 col-md-8 col-lg-8 col-xs-8 pre-panel datastore" id="students">

   //Some other codes here

 </div>

 <div class="col-sm-8 col-md-8 col-lg-8 col-xs-8 pre-panel datastore" id="teachers">

   //Some other codes here

 </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Do I really need an additional HTML element. Can't I just get it inside js only?

Comment: The additional HTML element is just here to show you the array of id.  But I edited to add it in JS

Comment: Anyway, it created only two empty nodes

Comment: What ? Aren't you looking for the array of ID ?

Comment: @Fasna As mentioned in my comment on the question, at what point are you running this code?  Is it perhaps before the ajax call that adds the `div`s with the `teacher` and `student` IDs have been added to the page?

Comment: I used them inside 
`$(document).ready(function() {
})`

Where the AJAX call for adding IDs also present

Comment: @Fasna That's why then - if they're being added through an ajax call, they simply won't exist when the code inside the `ready` callback runs.

Comment: I just now added your js part out of `ready` it also returns an empty array

Comment: @Fasna So there's another problem that we can't determine from your question (dynamic loading, duplicate id, etc.)

Comment: As I said in my question, I used the `console.log($("#data_stores"));` inside `ready`. I can see the ids of the elements. But, when I extend it for children I'm getting an empty array. That is the problem. Why I'm not allowed to dig into the element at the same point?